# Rails 3, add additional selection to collection select timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on some code that will allow the user to select their timezone. I this and it works swimmingly:

```
<%= select_tag :timezone, options_for_select(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING, cookies[:user_selected_timezone]) %>
```

I would like to append a couple of options to the list, ie. I would like the default to be "Select Your timezone here", and another option for "User your system timezone".

I tried something like:

```
<%= select_tag :timezone, options_for_select([[ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING], ["Select your timezone"]], cookies[:user_selected_timezone]) %>
```

...without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the extra options with the timezone mapping...

```
<%= select_tag :timezone, options_for_select(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.merge({"Use your system timezone" => "Use your system timezone", "Select your timezone" => ""}), cookies[:user_selected_timezone]) %>
```

Comment: Now, how would I get those options to the top of the list?

Comment: Well, you could always do the extra options first and merge the MAPPING after... `options_for_select({"Select your timezone" => "", "Use your system timezone"=>"Use your system timezone"}.merge(ActiveSupport::Timezone::MAPPING) ...`

Comment: Thanks Steve. You rock!